# How to reset HTML5 canvas after zooming?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create an HTML5-canvas based web app with zooming-to-cursor functionality.
The idea is simple:

- a user loads an image via standard HTML input;
- the image gets centered on a canvas;
- the user can zoom in/out the image to a cursor location;
- when the user loads another image, canvas gets cleared and reset;

I'm having troubles with the last step. When I load the first image, zoom in/out and then load the second image, I get the second image already zoomed to the scale of the previous image. I suppose the problem comes from `trackTransforms` function (took it [there](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html)), but I don't understand how it works, so I can't track down the issue.

Live code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Arkonage/tgkv21s8/22/

Comment: You have a `resetCanvas` function. Add a call to it to the beginning of the `handleImage` function.

Comment: This function clears the canvas (i.e. removes previous image), but it doesn't restore its state.

Comment: Ah, I see. `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` are overridden but still seem to be working. Call `ctx.save()` right after setting up, then call `ctx.restore(); ctx.save()` at the beginning of `resetCanvas`.

Comment: @Ouroborus hey, it works! Thank you! I knew there was something wrong with that quirky `trackTransforms` function. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution:

- Add `ctx.save();` to the beginning of the `trackTransforms()` function definition.
- Add `ctx.restore(); ctx.save();` to the beginning of the `resetCanvas()` function definition.